# Passing by refernce

Tags: c++, pointers, qt, reference

I am trying to understand the ideas of pointers and references in C++. I am stuck with the following, what would be the specific behaviour in this case? I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass{
public:
     MyClass(const QByteArray & raw){
        this->m_rawData =raw;
     }
private:
   QByteArray m_rawData;
}
```

Let's say I create the instance like this:

```
bool otherClass::someOtherMethod(){
    QByteArray data = QString("sometext").toUtf8();
    MyClass instance = new MyClass(data);
    return true;
}
```

I pass the `data` variable address to my class constructor, then I exit the local method of `OtherClass`. The `QByteArray data` will be destroyed and its memory freed, right? But what will happen in `MyClass instance` ? Will this

```
 MyClass(const QByteArray & raw){
            this->m_rawData =raw;
         }
```

actually copy the content of `raw` into `m_rawData` or will it copy the actual reference of the raw and `m_rawData` will become invalid when the `otherClass::someOtherMethod` returns?

Comment: `So the QByteArray data will be destroyed and its memory freed right?` -- No.  Your new class now holds a reference to it.  Even so, in C++, you're generally responsible for memory management unless you use a smart pointer (C++ is not a garbage-collected language), so if you fail to deallocate the memory, it will simply leak unless you maintain a reference to it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so this operation here `this->m_rawData =raw;` will copy the address of `raw` into `m_rawData` ? I was thinking that it would do something like this:   `QByteArray& operator=(const QByteArray &other) {
    
    this->c_str  = malloc(other.size()); 
    this->c_str = strcpy(other.c_str);  //etc ..

    return *this;
  }`

Comment: That's... not really what copying references does.

Comment: @RobertHarvey im trying to understand how references works, because they are better than object copying. But i was afraid of using them, because i thought that if i create the stack variable, and pass it reference in some class for example, i will later get a programm crash, because the reference would be invalid

Comment: In the example given, you are leaking the MyClass instance. If you omit the new, you won't leak `instance`, and thus won't leak `data`

Comment: I think the variable will be actually copied, because you have a value, not a reference on the left side.

Comment: @DavidPacker thanks exactly what i wanted to know! so i could declare a referenc member and it would hold the reference then? like : `private:
  const QByteArray & m_rawData;`

Comment: Yes, and then you have undefined behaviour when the passed element gets deleted after it leaves its scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the hood, it might be implemented differently, but the visible effect of

```
MyClass(const QByteArray & raw){
        this->m_rawData =raw;
}
```

will be that the contents of `raw` get copied into `m_rawData` and will survive after `raw` has been destructed.

This works because `m_rawData` is declared as being a value of type `QByteArray`. If it would have been a pointer or a reference, then it would have been left dangling if `raw` was destructed before `m_rawData`.

One important thing to remember in C++ is that everything is a value unless you explicitly make it a pointer or a reference.

Comment: Thanks i think thats the best answer it explains everything

Answer (score 0):

> ... copy the content of raw into m_rawData or it will copy the actual
>   reference of the raw and m_rawData will become invalid when the
>   otherClass::someOtherMethod returns?

```
this->m_rawData =raw;
```

will likely trigger the copy assignment operator on QByteArray. This is because you didn't initialize m_rawData in the initializer block and you therefore likely called the default constructor on QByteArray to initialize m_rawData.  After that occurred, in the ctor, your assigning the contents of data to m_rawData via copy assignment.

The default copy assignment operator probably is:

```
QByteArray &operator=(const QByteArray& other) {
  return *this;
}
```

which assigns values in other to this. However, the compiler generated assignment operator likely just returns a this pointer likely leaving all the values in QByteArray as garbage where nothing actually gets copied. (This is a good reason to 'delete' all the compiler generated class method in practice)

To fix this you need a valid copy assignment operator on  QByteArray.

Also this:

```
bool otherClass::someOtherMethod(){
    QByteArray data = QString("sometext").toUtf8();
    MyClass instance = new MyClass(data);  // leak!
    return true;
}
```

Memory should be owned. If you insist on dynamic memory do this:

```
bool otherClass::someOtherMethod(){
    QByteArray data = QString("sometext").toUtf8();
    std::unique_ptr<MyClass> fixed(new MyClass(data));
    return true;
}
```

> So the QByteArray data will be destroyed and its memory freed right?

Once the original stack variable 'data' goes out of scope it will trigger it's destructor.